# Conditionally combine multiple rows of SQL data into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is what my query returns:

```
SomeID     SomeActions                  PendingFlag     CompletedFlag
101        SomeAction1, SomeAction2     1               0
101        OtherAction1, OtherAction2   0               1
```

I need the above returned so that it looks like this

```
SomeID     SomeActionsPending           SomeActionsCompleted 
101        SomeAction1, SomeAction2     OtherAction1, OtherAction2
```

How can I write an MSSQL query that would combine data like this into one row based on the specific column flag?

Comment: Comma separated items... That will cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Data is imperfect. What happens if PendingFlag = 1 and CompletedFlag = 1, or both are = 0?

Answer (score 1):

I like conditional aggregation myself.

```
SELECT SomeID,
   SomeActionsCompleted = MAX(CASE CompletedFlag 
     WHEN 1 THEN SomeActions END), 
   SomeActionsPending   = MAX(CASE PendingFlag   
     WHEN 1 THEN SomeActions END)
 FROM ({ MyQuery }) AS MyQuery
 GROUP BY SomeID;
```

> [Example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fu7eW4n2)

Comment: This worked, it was so simple now that I see it. Thank you so much!